# Como abrir um arquivo unicode dentro de um zip?

Tags: python, arquivo-zip

Eu tentei

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("5.csv.zip", "r") as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
                line = readFile.readline()
                print(line)
                split = line.split('\t')
```

mas o resultado é:

```
b'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "zip.py", line 6
    split = line.split('\t')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Como farei para abrir esse arquivo como unicode ao invés de binário?

Comment: Fiz essa pergunta também em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601796/how-to-open-an-unicode-text-file-inside-a-zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você conhece a codificação correta do arquivo, basta utilizar a função `decode` no contéudo do arquivo (`string` se for Python 2, `bytes` ou `bytearray` se for Python 3):

```phyton
with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
    conteudo = readFile.read().decode(codificacao)
```

Como mencionado numa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602013/520779) à sua mesma pergunta no SO em inglês, tentar quebrar o conteúdo em linhas **antes de decodificar** é problemático, uma vez que codificações diferentes representam as quebras de linha de modo diferente. Entretanto, uma vez que você leu e decodificou **todo o conteúdo** do arquivo (através do `read`), você pode quebrá-lo em linhas normalmente uma vez que ele estará representado como uma string unicode (`unicode` se for Python 2, `string` se for Python 3):

```phyton
line = conteudo.split('\n')[0]
```

Ou por meio de uma expressão regular (para suportar `\n`, `\r` ou `\r\n`):

```phyton
line = re.split('\r?\n|\r', conteudo)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

A resposta dos gringos no SO foi

A razão pela qual você está vendo esse erro é porque você está tentando misturar bytes com unicode. O argumento para `split` também deve ser byte-string:

```
>>> line = b'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
>>> line.split(b'\t')
[b'$0.0', b'1822', b'1', b'1', b'1\n']
```

Para obter uma string unicode string, use [decode](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
>>> line.decode('utf-8')
'$0.0\t1822\t1\t1\t1\n'
```

Se você estiver iterando sobre o arquivo que você pode usar `codecs.iterdecode`, mas que não vai funcionar com 'readline()`.

```
with zfile.open(name, 'rU') as readFile:
    for line in codecs.iterdecode(readFile, 'utf8'):
        print line
        # etc
```